# How to train a random forest classification model for classifying multiclass data using scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have 4 sets of features X1,X2,X3&X4 and I have 8-10 possible outcomes i.e Y1-Y8. How would i train the model to fit this data? Should I for a particular output keep Yn as 1 and keep other Ys as 0?. If i do this while serving the model how do I ensure that I receive only discreet output values i.e 0 OR 1. 
How do I implement this in skilearn random forest classifier?

Comment: Do you want to predict all classes between Y1 to Y8 or only a single one?

Comment: No it has to be only one of the classes not multiple

Comment: Then you can directly use the sklearn random-forest with your data. No need to convert each label to binary.